# Handle different cast operation on same class property

Tags: python, casting, properties, python-3.10

Is there any way to handle casting a property of a class of type Any?
I'm converting an old project that loads text options from a database and puts them inside an object that represents them. Is there a way in which by means of a casting operation I can convert the string to the requested class before returning the requested value from the property?

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, value:str):
        self.__value = value
        
    @property
    def value(self) -> Any:
        return self.__value
    
example = Example("123")
int_example = int(example.value) //use some method to handle int cast and return a int value
str_example = str(example.value) //use other method (or the same with a parameter specifying the class) to handle the str cast and return a str value
```

During the initialization of the class I don't know the type associated with the string, but only when it is read

Answer (score 1):

You can add, `__int__` and `__str__` methods,

```
from typing import Any

class Example:
    def __init__(self, value:str):
        self.__value = value
        
    @property
    def value(self) -> Any:
        return self.__value
    
    def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return int(self.value, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return str(self.value, *args, **kwargs)

example = Example("123")
int_example = int(example) # or int(example.value)
str_example = str(example) # or str(example.value)
print(type(int_example))
print(type(str_example))
```

---

**Output:**

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```